# Why does transferring const char* arrays return just unicode?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that extracts random words from two pools that are inserted by the user and then every time that enter is pressed the prgram should print one from each but it just prints
`╠╠╠╠`

here's the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <stdlib.h>  
using namespace std;
void scenario(const char* direzioni[], const char* strutture[], int n1, int n2);
void print(string direzione, string struttura);
int autorun(bool fronte, int aspetattiva);
int caricadirezioni(const char* direzioni[], int n1);
int caricastrutture(const char* strutture[], int n2);
void load();
void save();
void reset(const char* direzioni[], const char* strutture[]);
int main()
{
    int turni = 0;
    int i;
    bool fronte = true;
    int aspettativa;
    int vaspettativa;
    string map;
    string mod;
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    int i4 = 0;
    const char* direzioni[1000];
    const char* strutture[1000];
    reset(direzioni, strutture);
    cout << "aspettativa turni:" << endl;
    cin >> aspettativa;
    if (turni == aspettativa)
    {
        vaspettativa = aspettativa;
        cout << "aspettativa di " << aspettativa << " turni raggiunta" << endl;
        cout << "nuova aspettativa:" << endl;
        cin >> aspettativa;
        while (aspettativa <= vaspettativa)
        {
            cout << "aspettativa non valida reinserire" << endl;
            cin >> aspettativa;
        }
    }
    cout << "Invio per tirare, a per generare autonomamente, c per caricare nuovi valori, x per chiudere" << endl;
    mod = getchar();
    do
    {
        mod = getchar();
        if (mod == "a")
        {
            turni = autorun(fronte, aspettativa);
            vaspettativa = aspettativa;
            cout << "aspettativa di " << aspettativa << " turni raggiunta" << endl;
            cout << "nuova aspettativa:" << endl;
            cin >> aspettativa;
            while (aspettativa <= vaspettativa)
            {
                cout << "aspettativa non valida reinserire" << endl;
                cin >> aspettativa;
            }
            cout << "Invio per tirare, a per generare autonomamente, x per chiudere" << endl;
            mod = getchar();
        }
        if (mod == "c")
        {
            n1 = caricadirezioni(direzioni, n1);
            n2 = caricastrutture(strutture, n2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "errore caricare i vettori" << endl;
                n1 = caricadirezioni(direzioni, n1);
                n2 = caricastrutture(strutture, n2);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << direzioni[i3] << endl;
                cout << strutture[i4] << endl;
                scenario(direzioni, strutture, n1, n2);
            }
            
        }
        if (turni == aspettativa)
        {
            vaspettativa = aspettativa;
            cout << "aspettativa di " << aspettativa << " turni raggiunta" << endl;
            cout << "nuova aspettativa:" << endl;
            cin >> aspettativa;
            while (aspettativa <= vaspettativa)
            {
                cout << "aspettativa non valida reinserire" << endl;
                cin >> aspettativa;
            }
            cout << "Invio per tirare, a per generare autonomamente, x per chiudere" << endl;
            mod = getchar();
        }


    } while (mod != "x");
}

void scenario(const char* direzioni[], const char* strutture[], int n1, int n2)
{
    string direzione;
    string struttura;

    int i3 = 0;
    int i4 = 0;
    i3 = rand() % n1 + 0;
    direzione = direzioni[i3];
    cout << "direzione: " << direzioni[i3] << endl;
    i4 = rand() % n2 + 0;
    struttura = strutture[i4];
    cout << "struttura: " << strutture[i4] << endl;

    

}
void print(string direzione, string struttura)
{
    ofstream print("map.txt", ofstream::app);
    
}
int autorun(bool fronte, int aspettativa)
{
    string direzione;
    string struttura;
    const char* direzionifronte[4] = { "avanti","bivio destra","avanti","bivio destra" };
    const char* strutturefronte[4] = { "deposito","nulla","nido di mitragliatrice","batteria" };
    int i3 = 0;
    int i4 = 0;
    int rando;
    const char* direzioni[6] = { "avanti","bivio destra","bivio sinistra","incrocio","destra","sinistra" };
    const char* struttureinterne[4] = { "deposito","nulla","b. ufficiali","b. dormitorio" };
    string direzioneinterna;
    string strutturainterna;
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int turni = 0;
    while (turni <= aspettativa)
    {
        if (!fronte)
        {
            i1 = rand() % 5 + 0;
            cout << "direzione: " << direzioni[i1] << endl;
            i2 = rand() % 3 + 0;
            cout << "struttura: " << struttureinterne[i2] << endl;
            direzioneinterna = direzioni[i1];
            strutturainterna = struttureinterne[i2];
            print(direzioneinterna, strutturainterna);
        }
        else
        {
            i3 = rand() % 3 + 0;
            cout << "direzione: " << direzionifronte[i3] << endl;
            i4 = rand() % 3 + 0;
            cout << "struttura: " << strutturefronte[i4] << endl;
            direzione = direzionifronte[i3];
            struttura = strutturefronte[i4];
            print(direzione, struttura);
            if (i3 == 1)
            {
                fronte = false;
            }
            if (i3 == 3)
            {
                fronte = true;
            }
        }
        turni++;
    }
    cout << "mappa generata con successo" << endl;
    return turni;
}
void reset(const char* direzioni[], const char* strutture[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000)
    {
        direzioni[i] = "_";
        strutture[i] = "_";
        i++;
    }
}
int caricadirezioni(const char* direzioni[], int n1)
{
    int i = 0;
    string direzione;
    cout << "Numero massimo di valori (max 1000)" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    while (i < n1)
    {
        cout << "direzione " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> direzione;
        direzioni[i] = direzione.data();
        i++;
    }
    return n1;
}
int caricastrutture(const char* strutture[], int n2)
{
    int i = 0;
    string struttura;
    cout << "Numero massimo di valori (max 1000)" << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    while (i < n2)
    {
        cout << "struttura " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> struttura;
        strutture[i] = struttura.data();
        cout << strutture[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return n2;
}
```

I think the problem might be from bringing the const char* arrays and I,ve tried converting them to string but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide contents of user input. For now tools are detecting errors in your code (may be result of invalid input): https://godbolt.org/z/r75EvqfKE

Comment: oh yeah I forgot, sorry. Anyway, you first have to enter a number (it can be whatever but that's not important),then press c (but just enter works anyway the first time)  and then it will ask first for a number (I suggest 1 or two) andsubsequently for a word, it will ask these two things two times, it should then show what you've typed every time you press enter but it doesn't

Comment: `╠` your compiler is trying to tell you about uninitialized stack memory. ╠ is 0xCC [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
int caricadirezioni(const char* direzioni[], int n1)
{
    int i = 0;
    string direzione;
    cout << "Numero massimo di valori (max 1000)" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    while (i < n1)
    {
        cout << "direzione " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> direzione;
        direzioni[i] = direzione.data();
        i++;
    }
    return n1;
}
```

`direzione` is local variable which lifetime ends as function execution ends. At the same time you are passing pointer to this string ourtside a function `direzioni[i] = direzione.data();`. So this pointer becomes invalid just after function `caricadirezioni` has finished execution.

This is what [address sanitizer finds](https://godbolt.org/z/r75EvqfKE).

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address 0x7fb530000070 at pc 0x7fb532bf1421 bp 0x7ffcbc8a2c00 sp 0x7ffcbc8a23c0
READ of size 2 at 0x7fb530000070 thread T0
    #0 0x7fb532bf1420  (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0x69420) (BuildId: 4508ebe68c8328f99c6a77c3715bff492eb1cfd5)
    #1 0x404d0d in std::char_traits<char>::length(char const*) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/char_traits.h:409
    #2 0x404d0d in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/ostream:668
    #3 0x404d0d in main /app/example.cpp:79
    #4 0x7fb531e29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #5 0x7fb531e29e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #6 0x405cd4 in _start (/app/output.s+0x405cd4) (BuildId: a9a752415f364c417747f92963b11d643730a5bb)

Address 0x7fb530000070 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 112 in frame
    #0 0x406def in caricadirezioni(char const**, int) /app/example.cpp:188

  This frame has 4 object(s):
    [48, 49) '<unknown>'
    [64, 65) '<unknown>'
    [80, 84) 'n1' (line 187)
    [96, 128) 'direzione' (line 190) <== Memory access at offset 112 is inside this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0x69420) (BuildId: 4508ebe68c8328f99c6a77c3715bff492eb1cfd5) 
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x7fb52ffffd80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb52ffffe00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb52ffffe80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb52fffff00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb52fffff80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x7fb530000000: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5[f5]f5
  0x7fb530000080: f5 f5 f5 f5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb530000100: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x7fb530000180: f5 f5 f5 f5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb530000200: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fb530000280: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1==ABORTING
```

`==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address` means you used variable after its lifetime ended.

`#3 0x404d0d in main /app/example.cpp:79` here consequence has been found.

`[96, 128) 'direzione' (line 190) <== Memory access at offset 112 is inside this variable` here address sanitizer finds which variable lifetime ended.

To fix this change array type from:

```cpp
    const char* direzioni[1000];
    const char* strutture[1000];
```

into

```cpp
    std::string direzioni[1000];
    std::string strutture[1000];
```

Please remember you are using C++ not C, so use C++ types.

Comment: thank you so much, I just tried it and now works flawlessly